# How to combine multiple object properties in select ng-options angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display both the text and number in my select options. JSON has different properties for text and number and I need to combine them and display in select options value by default.

Expected Output:
000.000.0001 - Chicago

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
  <select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items"></select>
  <p>Selected: {{model.selected}}</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
       {ID: '000.000.0001', Title: 'Chicago'},
       {ID: '000.000.0002', Title: 'New York'},
       {ID: '000.000.0003', Title: 'Washington'}
    ];  
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can assign multiple values using this approach

```
  <select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="item.ID  as item.ID + '-' + item.Title for item in items"></select>
  <p>Selected: {{model.selected}}</p>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.model = {
    selected : '000.000.0001'
  }
 $scope.items = [
       {ID: '000.000.0001', Title: 'Chicago'},
       {ID: '000.000.0002', Title: 'New York'},
       {ID: '000.000.0003', Title: 'Washington'}
    ];  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-model="model.selected" ng-options="item.ID  as item.ID + '-' + item.Title for item in items"></select>
  <p>Selected: {{model.selected}}</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: THanks for the answer, but am looking the select options dropdown should have this combination.

Comment: @M-S check the demo again

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for this. I accepted the answer, can you please make the first one to be default. Now it is not.

Comment: check it now !!

Comment: This works fine for the example but what if the separator `'-'` has to be  a translated label? How do you deal with the `translate` directive?